# Passing variables to HTTPS-triggered cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Cloud Composer, and I have a DAG that has one task that calls an HTTPS-triggered cloud function that sends out an email (due to restrictions on the project I'm working on, I had to do it this way).
The most simple form of this works. I can trigger the cloud function, and the emails are being sent successfully. However, I want to pass some variables I'm defining in the DAG to the Cloud Function, and this is where something is failing. I was using the usual way to pass parameters to the request URL.

This was the way I was defining the DAG:

```py
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Import Libraries
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import datetime
    from airflow.models import DAG
    from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator,BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator
    from airflow.providers.google.common.utils import id_token_credentials as id_token_credential_utils
    import google.auth.transport.requests
    from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Set variables
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    (...)
    report_name_url = "report_name_url"
    end_user = "end_user@email.com"
    
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Functions
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def invoke_cloud_function():
        url = "https://<trigger_url>?report_name_url={}&end_user={}".format(report_name_url, end_user) #I'M ADDING THE STRINGS TO THE URL AFTER THE ?, TO PASS WHAT I WANT AS ARGUMENTS TO THE CLOUD FUNCTION  
        
        request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()  #this is a request for obtaining the the credentials
            id_token_credentials = id_token_credential_utils.get_default_id_token_credentials(url, request=request) # If your cloud function url has query parameters, remove them before passing to the audience 
    
        resp = AuthorizedSession(id_token_credentials).request("GET", url=url) # the authorized session object is used to access the Cloud Function
    
        print(resp.status_code) # should return 200
        print(resp.content) # the body of the HTTP response

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Define DAG
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    with DAG(
        dag_id,
        schedule_interval= '0 13 05 * *', # DAG Cron scheduler
        default_args = default_args) as dag:
            
            (...)
            
            send_email = PythonOperator(
                task_id="send_email", 
                python_callable=invoke_cloud_function
            )
        
            start >> run_stored_procedure >> composer_logging >> send_email >> end
```

This is what I have as far as the DAG goes. From the perspective of the cloud function, I have the following:

```py
    def send_email(request):
      import ssl
      from email.message import EmailMessage
      import smtplib
      import os 
    
      report_name_url = request.args.get('report_name_url')
      report_name = report_name_url.replace("_", " ")
      end_user = request.args.get('end_user')
    
    (...)
    
      context = ssl.create_default_context()
    
      with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(sender_email, password)
        smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, em.as_string())
```

Can someone point me toward a solution for my use-case?

Thank you very much.

Edit for added context:

I'm getting the following information from the logs:

```
"(...)Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>...</code>.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n'"
```

This is odd because I think this was the error I was getting BEFORE giving permissions to my service account to invoke the cloud function.
Now, that permission is in place.

The only problem I foresee is that I'm not exactly calling the original URL that triggers the cloud function, since I'm adding parameters. Could this be the problem?

**EDIT:**

After a lot of digging around, I found a way to do this. First and foremost, I had to switch from GET to POST. This way, I was able to pass the URL that indeed is meant to trigger the Cloud Function.
The final solution came down to this:

This was the function in the DAG:

```
def invoke_cloud_function_success():
    url = "<trigger url>" #the url is also the target audience. 
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()  #this is a request for obtaining the the credentials


    id_token_credentials = 
id_token_credential_utils.get_default_id_token_credentials(url, request=request) # If your cloud function url has query parameters, remove them before passing to the audience 

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    body = {"report_name":report_name, "end_user":end_user, "datastudio_link":datastudio_link}
    resp = AuthorizedSession(id_token_credentials).post(url=url, json=body, headers=headers) # the authorized session object is used to access the Cloud Function

    print(resp.status_code) # should return 200
    print(resp.content) # the body of the HTTP response
```

In the final Cloud Function I had to put:

```
  request_json = request.get_json()
  report_name = list(request_json['report_name'])
  datastudio_link = list(request_json['datastudio_link'])
  end_user = list(request_json['end_user'])
```

Comment: How do you know something is failing? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: Something is failing because the emails aren't being sent out, so the cloud function is not getting triggered.

Comment: @ianyoung I added to the post the message I am getting in the logs

Comment: Are you sure that's a recent error message? I wouldn't have thought adding params would alter request permissions. A couple of things to check: 1) Can you request the plain URL using the service account without error? 2) Try including the name of the function in the request: `https://<REGION>-<PROJECT>.cloudfunctions.net/send_email?report_name_url=test`

Comment: yes, the error was recent. And I'm able to request the plain URL using the service account.

I've tried a number of different approaches in the last days, suggested by colleagues who use cloud functions regularly. Still, I'm stuck.